# Create new account through integration

Tags: usability-integration

I work for Application R. We are currently building an integration with the AppJ. Our Users will have to create new accounts for their Clients in AppJ. They need to do it through Application R interface. The problem is: it needs zero development time from the AppJ.

So the flow is as follows: Application R Users fills in the form for a Client, clicks "send" and the new account in AppJ is created with the Client's email address and details.

My problem is: the password. AppJ has its requirements as to the syntax of the password and we meet it. However, if Client wants to login to the AppJ, he needs the password. Currently, he can do it through "recover password" functionality.

I am not sure how to make it more user friendly and understandable if I cannot count on AppJ Dev Team.

Comment: These are two different Users.

Comment: Could you please add more details on AppJ user registration workflow? I.e. as if your client register in AppJ directly.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like you just need to present the user with some useful information once they create a new account (in Application R).

So once the user has submitted the form, show the something like this:

---

> Your new account in Application J has been created.

> To access your new account you will first need to reset your password in application J.

> You can reset your password here: [link to application J recover password](http://www.example.com)

Comment: Another problem is that the person filling in the form (creating account) and the account user are two different people. It's not enough that I show this info to the User. I need toi inform User's Client that he can create password by "recovering it".

Comment: Then start by saying "Send the following information to your client:" Or, capture the client's email address and get your app to send this information directly to them as an email.